# Looking to modify a Scrapy Amazon Product Spyder

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to Python and Scrapy, and I've been looking for ways to web scrape products information from Amazon. I'm working on a pet project of mine that will help me select OTC vitamin supplement better. I found it tedious to be opening each individual product just to look at the ingredients of the supplement, so I thought I could learn web scraping to expedite this process.

[Section that I'm trying to scrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v6X8.png)

I tried modifying the existing Amazon Product Review from Scrapy github

The bolded text is my attempts at modifying the original code to scrape the data that I wanted.

import json
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import re

class AmazonSearchProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "amazon_search_product"

```
custom_settings = {
    'FEEDS': { 'data/%(name)s_%(time)s.csv': { 'format': 'csv',}}
    }

def start_requests(self):
    keyword_list = ['vitamin']
    for keyword in keyword_list:
        amazon_search_url = f'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={keyword}&page=1'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=amazon_search_url, callback=self.discover_product_urls, meta={'keyword': keyword, 'page': 1})

def discover_product_urls(self, response):
    page = response.meta['page']
    keyword = response.meta['keyword'] 

    ## Discover Product URLs
    search_products = response.css("div.s-result-item[data-component-type=s-search-result]")
    for product in search_products:
        relative_url = product.css("h2>a::attr(href)").get()
        product_url = urljoin('https://www.amazon.com/', relative_url).split("?")[0]
        yield scrapy.Request(url=product_url, callback=self.parse_product_data, meta={'keyword': keyword, 'page': page})
        
    ## Get All Pages
    if page == 1:
        available_pages = response.xpath(
            '//*[contains(@class, "s-pagination-item")][not(has-class("s-pagination-separator"))]/text()'
        ).getall()

        last_page = available_pages[-1]
        for page_num in range(2, int(last_page)):
            amazon_search_url = f'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={keyword}&page={page_num}'
            yield scrapy.Request(url=amazon_search_url, callback=self.discover_product_urls, meta={'keyword': keyword, 'page': page_num})


def parse_product_data(self, response):
    image_data = json.loads(re.findall(r"colorImages':.*'initial':\s*(\[.+?\])},\n", response.text)[0])
    variant_data = re.findall(r'dimensionValuesDisplayData"\s*:\s* ({.+?}),\n', response.text)
    feature_bullets = [bullet.strip() for bullet in response.css("#feature-bullets li ::text").getall()]
    price = response.css('.a-price span[aria-hidden="true"] ::text').get("")

    ingredients_data = response.css('important-information::text').get("") # My attempted modification

    if not price:
        price = response.css('.a-price .a-offscreen ::text').get("")
    yield {
        "name": response.css("#productTitle::text").get("").strip(),
        "price": price,
        "stars": response.css("i[data-hook=average-star-rating] ::text").get("").strip(),
        "rating_count": response.css("div[data-hook=total-review-count] ::text").get("").strip(),
        "feature_bullets": feature_bullets,
        "images": image_data,
        "variant_data": variant_data,

        "ingredients": ingredients_data # My attempted modification

    }
```

I was hoping to successfully extract the data from the ingredient section of the important information, but all I got were blanks.

Comment: Try to inspect each stage(function) of your scrapy class. I think the best methods would either inspectResponse or scrapy shell. Please let me if need more help.

Comment: create a [mre].